# Disable screen rotation at runtime on Android

Tags: android

```
public class testScreenRotation extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private int mRuntimeOrientation;
   private boolean mDisableScreenRotation=true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mRuntimeOrientation = this.getScreenOrientation();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
protected int getScreenOrientation() {
/*
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = display.getOrientation();

    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
       orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

       if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
          if (display.getWidth() == display.getHeight())
             orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
          else if(display.getWidth() < display.getHeight())

             orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
          else
             orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
          }
       }


    return orientation;
  */
    return Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
 }
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (mDisableScreenRotation) {
             super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
             this.setRequestedOrientation(mRuntimeOrientation);
          } else {
             mRuntimeOrientation = this.getScreenOrientation();
             super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
          }
       }

}
```

my app as above ,and add android:configChanges="orientation" in the xml.when  my app start my screen is PORTRAIT,i press ctrl+F12,the screen also roate,the screen is LANDSCAPE,second i  press ctrl+F12,the screen also roate,the screen is PORTRAIT,then i  press ctrl+F12,the screen keep PORTRAIT. so i press again,the screen  keep PORTRAIT. my question is that why my screen not keep  PORTRAIT when the app start.

Edit:i want to use code to control the screen roate, if i can do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are trying to get your application to be in Portrait-mode all the time, you can this line to the element in the manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Add This line in each activity in  the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: thank you  for answer.i also i can use code to keep the screen portrait

Comment: @pengwang Did it solve your problem? If so, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: thanks ,i should solved my question,you can test my answer. thank you for your answer.

Comment: This worked for me, even though the whole `android:configChanges="orientation"` trick didn't. Cheers!

Comment: This answer sets the orientation for the whole activity, and not at runtime but at compile time... not sure why this got accepted as a valid answer, but it should be updated to reflect what it really does.

Comment: @Andres If you read the answer it clearly states "... Portrait-mode all the time ...". "All the time" being key here..

Answer (score 7):

I believe the method you are looking for is `Activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_<PORTRAIT/LANDSCAPE>)`

This together with

`android:configChanges="orientation"`

for that activity in the manifest to tell the system you will handle the orientation yourself should disable automatic reorientation.

Comment: i have soled the problem ,but i donot need the android:configChanges="orientation"

Answer (score 4):

Change the AndroidManifest.xml file. Thats enough.

`<activity android:name="Activity_Name"            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>`

Now your app will not change the Orientation.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i hope Disable screen rotation at runtime use code .

Answer (score 3):

http://androidbiancheng.blogspot.com/2010/10/java-setrequestedorientation.html, this link solved my question, setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);and not need add the line android:configChanges="orientation" in xml.so  i think i cannot use Configuration to get the screen Orientation,should use ActivityInfo.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable screen rotation on runtime from java source code as well.
Just try this way

```
private void setAutoRotation(final boolean autorotate) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    IWindowManager wm = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
                    if (autorotate) {
                        wm.thawRotation();
                    } else {
                        wm.freezeRotation(-1);
                    }
                } catch (RemoteException exc) {
                    Log.secW(TAG, "Unable to save auto-rotate setting");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now try to call this method during your application runtime. May be in some methods or on some buttons.

```
setAutoRotation(false);

setAutoRotation(true);
```